# How to avoid data extraction from website into Excel

Tags: text-extraction

Is there already a way to avoid that all or some content of a website can be extracted by Excel or Distiller or Acrobat Reader?

For example, a php page containing a table loaded with MySQL values

CSS is not a definitive answer for this...   ; )

```
Code:
<style type="text/css">
.deselect ::selection {
background: transparent;
color: inherit;
}
.deselect ::-moz-selection {
background: transparent;
color: inherit;
}
</style>




<body>
---------------------------------------
<div class="deselect"> (data viewer)

</div>
</body>
```

Comment: You can make it hard for them by serving the data as an image. I wouldn't recommend that, though.

Comment: @Gabe Yes, specialy when we are talking about a huge quantity of data...